# I started a project for iPhone and iPad but i want to remove the iPad

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been looking and i cant find an answer, but I started a project that would be for both iphone and ipad, but i've decided only to do it for iphone. how do i remove the ipad section? and would it still be able to download for ipad? i just dont want to have 2 different Storyboards, I want the app to still be compatible with the ipad but as an iphone app, like the apps you have that run in the size of an iphone screen and you can make them bigger

Please help! thanks

Comment: I want it to be universal, but how do i remove the ipad portion out of my project?

Comment: Then it is not a **truly** universal app. The answers in the linked question directly answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In build setting for your project you should set **Targeted Device Family** to iPhone only.

You can then delete your iPad Storyboard. You may have to change you **main storyboard file base name** in your info plist to the correct one.